# DNA to RNA transcription in Swift

Tags: swift, string, dna-sequence

I'm trying to return an RNA complement given a DNA strand (a string) in Swift. Basically, if DNA has a "T", I replace it with a "U".

My code is:

```
func toRNA(DNA: String) -> String{
    var RNA = DNA
    for ntide in RNA{
        if ntide == "T"{
            ntide = "U"
        }
    }
    return RNA
}
```

Swift:: Error:

> cannot assign to value: 'ntide' is a 'let' constant

```
ntide = "U"
~~~~~ ^
```

Comment: you'll need a map here. Like this, for example: https://useyourloaf.com/blog/swift-guide-to-map-filter-reduce/

Comment: Do you understand the cause of the error and you just need to find a solution around the error or do you not understand the error at all?

Comment: I don't understand the error. My guess is that characters inside of strings are considered constant and thus cannot be changed.

Comment: @KevinTrinh No. The error is because variables declared in a `for` loop are `let` constants.

Comment: Ah, that helps a lot. Still new to Swift. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is caused by the fact that the variable declared in a `for ... in ...` loop is immutable. For a simple `Collection`, you would just iterate through the range of indexes present in the `Collection` and use subscripts to access the values of your mutable variable.

```
func toRNA(_ DNA:[Character])->String{
    var RNA = DNA
    for i in 0..<DNA.count {
        if RNA[i] == "T" {
            RNA[i] = "U"
        }
    }
    return String(RNA)
}

let dna:[Character] = ["A","C","G","T"]
toRNA(dna) //"ACGU"
```

However, due to the differences of `String` indexing and subscript, this wouldn't be so simple for your problem, hence the above example uses `Array<Character>` to show the generic method. For your specific issue with Strings, see the below workarounds.

You can get around this issue by rather than copying `DNA` to `RNA` and then iterating through `RNA` to chance the necessary characters, you simply iterate through `DNA` and change what character to add to it.

```
func toRNA(DNA: String) -> String{
    var RNA = ""
    for char in DNA {
        if char == "T" {
            RNA.append("U")
        } else {
            RNA.append(char)
        }
    }
    return RNA
}
```

A simpler solution that doesn't solve the specific problem, but works for this specific question is to use a simple `map` to convert all characters which are `"T"` to `"U"`.

```
func toRNA(DNA: String) -> String{
    return String(DNA.map({$0=="T" ? "U" : $0}))
}
```

Comment: This works! Looks like I should start learning about maps too.

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
func toRNA(DNA: String) -> String{
    return DNA.replacingOccurrences(of: "T", with: "U")
}
```

Comment: For the use-case as described in the question, yes. In actuality, there's a couple more replacements to be made.

Comment: I know :) Let's fix one thing at a time.

Comment: @Gereon But this answer won't help the OP solve the real problem they are trying to solve.

Comment: I tried running your code. However, I ended up getting a different error instead:

Swift:: Error: value of type 'String' has no member 'replacingOccurencesOf'
    return DNA.replacingOccurencesOf("T", with: "U")
           ^~~ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Comment: Sorry, my bad, typed from memory, fixed now. @rmaddy: When I wrote this, all I had to go on was the original question.

Comment: Am I suppose to import anything to use replacingOccurences? I tried your suggestion but it didn't work.

Comment: Yes, you need to `import Foundation`.